# Display TextView Bottom of the Screen in Android

Tags: android, layout, textview

In my application, 
i want to display one TextView in Top of the Screen with screen width. next want to display graphical view below that TextView. next display one Text View below that Graphical View.

I used following xml code. In my code TextView couldnt display in bottom of the screeen.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
<TextView  
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/hello"
android:background="#FF8A11"
android:padding="8dip"
/>
</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
<com.game.viewdot.ViewDot
 android:id="@+id/DrawView"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />   
 </LinearLayout>



 <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"  
>

<TextView  

android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Another Text View"
android:background="#FF8A11"
android:padding="8dip"
android:gravity="bottom"
 android:layout_gravity="bottom"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

What modification i want to put in this code to get my result??????

Comment: Why dont you use `RelativeLayout` ? Again edit the layout so that it can viewed properly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using LinearLayout as a parent layout use Relative Layout.
Try to use the following code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relative01"
        >
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:background="#FF8A11" 
        android:padding="8dip"
        android:id="@+id/textView01"
        />
        <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView01"
    >
    <com.game.viewdot.ViewDot
 android:id="@+id/DrawView"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />   
     </LinearLayout>



     <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >

    <TextView  

    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Another Text View"
    android:background="#FF8A11"
    android:padding="8dip"

    />

    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this will help you...:)

Comment: But being a developer i want to know that is it possible to do so through linear layout ?

Comment: @PrateekBhardwaj yes u can do the same using Linear layout also.

Answer (score 19):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_gravity="bottom">

<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/ContentView"
android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you need `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` ?

Answer (score 0):

set all linearlayout height

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Comment: if i set fill parent to all layout means Top TextView only display.

Answer (score 0):

set android:layout_height="fill_parent" property for all View expect TextView....

Comment: if i set like this means top TextView only displayed.

Comment: u had used RelativeLayout? i m sure it will work fine.. n plz edit your code properly bcz some code is not visible

Comment: I used relative layout. now my top textView couldnt display. <TextView  
    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:background="#FF8A11"
    android:padding="8dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    /> i used above things for top text view.